# Error due to C drive user folder name with spaces, while importing Theano

Tags: python-2.7, g++, anaconda, theano

I'm using `Windows 8.1 64-bit` on a `Dell Inspiron 15r 5521, core i5 3rd generation`. I have installed `Anaconda2 4.3.1 64-bit version` and am trying to import `theano` after installing it.
The user folder name is `C:\Users\Muhammad Ahsan Anjum` without the quotes. Its giving error because it simply takes the path till it encounters the first space character(the path being somewhere in `C:\Users\Muhammad Ahsan Anjum\AppData\Local`). How do I make it take the full path including the spaces, so that Theano is compiled?
This is what I get after typing "import theano" in my Python environment:

```
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
"C:\SciSoft\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++.exe" -shared -g -march=ivybridge -mmmx -mno-3dnow -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -mno-sse4a -mcx16 -msahf -mno-movbe -maes -mno-sha -mpclmul -mpopcnt -mno-abm -mn
o-lwp -mno-fma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mno-bmi -mno-bmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx -mno-avx2 -msse4.2 -msse4.1 -mno-lzcnt -mno-rtm -mno-hle -mrdrnd -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mno-rdseed -mno-prfchw -mno-adx -mfxsr
-mxsave -mxsaveopt -mno-avx512f -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512pf -mno-prefetchwt1 -mno-clflushopt -mno-xsavec -mno-xsaves -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512bw -mno-avx512vl -mno-avx512ifma
-mno-avx512vbmi -mno-clwb -mno-pcommit --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=3072 -mtune=ivybridge -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DM
S_WIN64 -I"C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2\include" -I"C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof" -L"C:\ProgramFiles
\Anaconda2\libs" -L"C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2" -o C:\Users\Muhammad Ahsan Anjum\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-
64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\Muhammad Ahsan Anjum\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker
_ext\mod.cpp -lpython27
g++.exe: error: Anjum\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd: No such file or dire
ctory
g++.exe: error: C:\Users\Muhammad: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Anjum\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp: No such file or directory

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano_init_.py", line 66, in 
from theano.compile import (
File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile_init_.py", line 10, in 
from theano.compile.function_module import *
File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 21, in 
import theano.compile.mode
File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 10, in 
import theano.gof.vm
File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 662, in 
from . import lazylinker_c
File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in 
preargs=args)
File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2316, in compile_str
(status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): g++.exe: error: Anjum\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazyli
. g++.exe: error: Anjum\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug with a fix only in the dev version](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5767).

- So you should uninstall theano:

  `conda uninstall theano`
- [Download](https://github.com/Theano/Theano) the library from the git project and unzip it somewhere (e.g. on `C:\Users\Muhammad Anjum`)
- Enter the unziped folder (e.g. `cd C:\Users\Muhammad Anjum\Theano-master`) on your Anaconda Prompt and install it:

  `pip install -e .`